# onreadystatechange only firing once

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following code for my request:

```
     var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState == 4)       // state of 4 is 'done'. The request has completed
    {
     callback(req.responseText); // The .responseText property of the request object
    } else {                       // contains the Text returned from the request.
      console.log(req.readyState);
    }
  };
  req.open("GET", url, true);
  req.send();
```

However, the readyState is changing to 1 and firing correctly (I'm seeing it echoed in the console) but it simply won't progress to 2. After awhile it times out and I get this in the console:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Anyone have any idea why this might be?

Comment: `What are you trying to load? it has nothing to do with the code you are showing, that all looks good.

Comment: It's just a URL command for a PHP script (which definitely works). So, I'm basically sending something like "cmd=login&sessionID=1" appended to the URL and I'll be receiving back JSON data that I'm parsing elsewhere.

Comment: So, typing the url as it's being sent with the GET request, into your browser actually returns the JSON?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, containing various commands/messages to be parsed and handled

I should note: that WOULD be correct, but the server where the API I'm using is accessible only on-server or via a specific VPN connection.

Comment: are you trying to send request to another domain ?

Comment: It's a separate server on the same network. However, I'd had this working previously and reaching readyState == 4 just fine. And then it'd randomly stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Put this

```
req.open("GET", url, true);
  req.send();
```

above this line

```
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
```

Comment: This just broke the request send altogether... :(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all, this ended up being a VPN issue, not a scripting one.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getLatestfileinAllPath(urls)?
{
    for(i = 0;i<urls.length;i++){
        run(i)
    }
    function run(){
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('POST', url[i]);
        request.send(JSON.stringify({"data":"some data"}));
        request.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (request.readyState  === XMLHttpRequest.DONE  && request.status == 200)
            {
                console.log(JSON.parse(request.response));
            }
         }
        }; 
    }
}
```